# content type of http response changes when using external clients but is correct in unit test

Tags: http, go

I have a strange situation. I want to return the content type `application/json; charset=utf-8` from an http handler.

```
func handleTest() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Header.Get("Accept") != "application/json" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotAcceptable)
            return
        }
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"foo": "bar"})
    }
}
```

When I check for this in my unit tests it is correct. This test does not fail.

```golang
func TestTestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/test", nil)
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    response := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handleTest().ServeHTTP(response, request)
    contentType := response.Header().Get("Content-Type")
    if contentType != "application/json; charset=utf-8" {
        t.Errorf("Expected Content-Type to be application/json; charset=utf-8, got %s", contentType)
        return
    }
}
```

But when I try with curl (and other clients) it comes out as `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

```c
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' localhost:8080/test -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: application/json
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 13:02:27 GMT
< Content-Length: 14
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
{"foo":"bar"}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I have tried this with curl, insomnia and python. In all 3 cases the content type came out as `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [http package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter):

> WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with the provided status code.

and

> Changing the header map after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers.

So you are setting the "Content-Type" header after the header has already been sent out to the client. While mocking this likely works because the buffer where the headers are stored can be modified after the `WriteHeader` call. But when actually using a TCP connection you can't do this.

So simply move your `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` so it happens after the `w.Header().Set(...)`